# Posterior distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, density-function, posterior, pareto-distribution

Suppose $X1,..,X4$ be iid from pdf $f(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ ,for $0<x<\theta$.

The prior distribution is

$\pi(\theta)=\frac{2}{\theta^3}$ , for $\theta>1$

I have to obtain:

a)posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $Y$, where $Y = max(X1,...,X4)$.

b)point estimate of $\theta$ based on median of posterior.

**My work**

a) Starting with pdf of $Y$, $f_{X(4)}(y)=\frac{4y^3}{\theta^4}$ ; using the formula for pdf of $X_{(n)}$

Calculating joint pdf $f(y,\theta)$

$f(y,\theta)=\frac{8y^3}{\theta^7}$

Posterior distribution $f(\theta|y) \propto \frac{1}{\theta^7}$

$f(\theta|y)=\frac{6}{\theta^7} \sim pareto(1,6)$ [By normalization]

Could you please let me know whether my approach for posterior is correct.

Also, for part (b), should I be obtaining the MLE for posterior distribution.
I would appreciate your feedback, and pointers.

Comment: Two things to think about:  1) In your posterior, there's nothing to prevent $\theta < Y$ (why does this matter?), and 2) Imagine rescaling your data from, e.g., meters to centimeters.  Your posterior should automatically change to reflect this.  Will it?  What's missing from your posterior?

Comment: @jbowman I agree, in this case since it is uniform, it doesn't really matter. But the question in hand needs distribution of $\theta|Y$. And I can't really write $\theta|X \approx \theta|Y$. The answer is same if I use $X$ instead of $Y$, as it would take maximum of $Xi$. But the real problem is in understanding **point estimate for $\theta$ based on the median of posterior**. What does it really mean?

Comment: The issue is that your posterior isn't correct.  The first point does matter, as $\theta > Y$, it can't be otherwise, but you have no such information in your posterior.  The second point matters because if all your data is rescaled by, e.g., multiplying by 10, your posterior doesn't appear to change, but obviously it ought to, as $\theta$ would be multiplied by 10 as well, so the posterior has to be different.